# Проверить cookies в Django проекте

Tags: django, cookie

Никак не могу разобраться, помогите, пожалуйста. Задача такая: когда юзер впервые заходит на вебсайт, всплывает окно с информацией о том, сайт собирает файлы куки. После нажатия кнопки "согласен" (или "принимаю"), django проверяет информацию о сохраненных куки и у юзера такое сообщение не всплывает, пока браузер хранит эти куки.

Comment: можете тут посмотреть https://github.com/TyMaszWeb/django-cookie-law

Comment: это возможно работает, но совершенно не понятно. Не могу понять как вызывается файл cookielaw_tags.py. У меня ошибка в html {% trans "COOKIE_INFO_HEADER" %} не находит

Comment: можно сделать только на фронтенде https://github.com/osano/cookieconsent

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://www.osano.com/cookieconsent/download/) есть удобный и простой конструктор на JavaScript
Любой справится.